# Oracle Apex 5.1 (How to add custom link additional to default link on Interactive report)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How to add additional custom link to modal dialogue page from Interactive report in Oracle Apex 5.1

I want to show this link only when flag is Y  for specific rows.

What will be the best way to do it...

Answer (score 2):

Create a link (using `f?p` syntax) as a column in report. As you only want to display it when some condition is met, use `CASE` (or `DECODE`), e.g.

```
select 
  id,
  name,
  --
  case when flag = 'Y' then 'f?p=&APP_ID.:3:'||&SESSION.||'::NO::P3_POG:4005 
       else null
  end as link,
  --
  etc.
from your_table
where ...
```

In this example, I'm calling page #3 and passing 4005 to P3_POG item value.

A better option (as Jeffrey suggested) would be

```
case when flag = 'Y' then 
          apex_page.get_url(p_page=>3, p_items=>'P3_POG', p_values=>my_id) 
end as link
```

Don't forget to set *escaping special characters* property for the LINK column.

Comment: I would recommend using the APEX API to generate the link, e.g. `case when flag = 'Y' then apex_page.get_url(p_page=>3, p_items=>'P3_POG', p_values=>my_id) end as link`

Comment: Hi thank you... I have used APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL. It's wonderful!

Comment: You're welcome (I suppose @Jeffrey is happy as well :)).